# Strings in bounding box coordinates

Tags: python, image-processing, bounding-box, scikit-image

I have used the regionsprops function on a labelled image to obtain bounding box coordinates and sizes. when I access a bounding box coordinate, I get a tuple with the string "L" in it. I cannot understand why there would be a string inside a tuple for coordinates and sizes.

Printing the bounding box coordinates returns `(0L, 393L, 29L, 463L)`, whereas it would make life much easier if it returned `(0, 393, 29, 463)` instead.

I am not able to draw a bounding box since the tuple is not considered a numerical tuple `TypeError: points is not a numerical tuple`. How can I use this tuple to draw a bounding box on an image.

```
properties = skimage.measure.regionprops(labelled_image)
boundingbox = properties[0].bbox

print boundingbox # returns (0L, 393L, 29L, 463L)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suffix `L` or `l` indicates a `long` integer.
`long` was merged with `int` in Python 3.

If you are on Python 2.x, these numbers shouldn't cause any problems and can be *treated like integers*.